# Does Abathur's Adrenal Overload buff his Monstrosity's attack speed?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When I use my Q on my pet, do I give it increased attack speed, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could of course try this on "try mode" :

- Go to shop
- Select Abathur
- Select "Try mode"
- Level up
- See if his attack speed is increased

However, there already is some info on the battle net forums, with someone claiming (24/04/2015 - [link](http://eu.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/14381659298)):

> the 25% attack speed buff from adrenal overload does not work for the monstrosity when you control it with symbiote.
>
> tested in coop and try out mode - doesnt work.

Comment: Although you give a method to check this wouldn't it be a better response if you added the result too?

Comment: Hello and welcome to arqade.   Your answer has been flagged because it does not meet the quality standard of what we are looking for in a answer.   To fix this please expand on your answer as to what you noticed when you played abathur.

Comment: Well... I can't launch HotS right now, since nobody answered, I thought giving a way to solve this question was the right thing to do.    
 Might edit my answer with a proper result in a few hours if there is still no answer.

Comment: @Seekme thanks for contributing with answering the answer, the problem is like +Virusboy said, when someone enter in SE sites looking for an answer, they're especting an answer with all he/she need to solve his/her problem. Without the need to ***test** (when you're not sure that the solution will works or not)* or ***links-only** (everyone likes a good source, but if the source by some reason goes off, the answer is lost)*.

Comment: Here are some links that may help with answering questions: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [How do I write a good answer to a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/159220), [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @Seekme hey man, there are still no answers and I'm dying to find out. Can you edit your answer so I can upvote and accept?

Comment: Edited, hope this is not too late, I can still test it by myself if you need it.